# Run Omnet++ inside docker with x11 forwarding on windows. SSH not working

Tags: docker, dockerfile, omnet++, x11-forwarding, docker-for-windows

### Cannot ssh into container running on Windows hostmachine

For a university project i build a docker image containing Omnet++ to provide a consistent development environment.

The Image uses phusions's Baseimage and sets up x11 forwarding via SSH like rogaha did in his [docker-desktop](https://github.com/rogaha/docker-desktop/blob/master/Dockerfile) image.

The image works perfectly fine on a Linux Host System. But on Windows and OS X i was unable to ssh on the container from the host machine.

I reckon this is due to the different implementation of Docker on Windows and OS X. As explained in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/container-networking#transparent-network) Article by Microsoft Docker uses a NAT Network for Containers as a default to Separate the Networks from Host and Containers.

---

My problem is i don't know how to reach the running container via ssh. 
I already tried the following:

- Change the Container Network to a transparent Network as described in the Microsoft Article. The following error occurs both in Windows and OS X:

```
docker network create -d transparent MyTransparentNetwork
Error response from daemon: legacy plugin: plugin not found
```

- On Windows run Docker in Virtualbox instead of Hyper-V
- Explicitly expose port 22 like this:

```
docker run -p 52022:22 containerName
ssh -p 52022 root@ContainerIP
```

### Dockerfile

```
FROM phusion/baseimage:latest
MAINTAINER Robin Finkbeiner 
LABEL Description="Docker image for Nesting Stupro University of Stuttgart containing full omnet 5.1.1"

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    xpra\
    rox-filer\
    openssh-server\
    pwgen\
    xserver-xephyr\
    xdm\
    fluxbox\
    sudo\
    git \
    xvfb\
    wget \
    build-essential \
    gcc \
    g++\
    bison \
    flex \
    perl \
    qt5-default\
    tcl-dev \
    tk-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    default-jre \
    doxygen \
    graphviz \
    libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 \
    libqt4-opengl-dev \
    openscenegraph-plugin-osgearth \
    libosgearth-dev\
    openmpi-bin\
    libopenmpi-dev

# Set the env variable DEBIAN_FRONTEND to noninteractive
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

#Enabling SSH -- from phusion baseimage documentation 
RUN rm -f /etc/service/sshd/down

# Regenerate SSH host keys. baseimage-docker does not contain any, so you
# have to do that yourself. You may also comment out this instruction; the
# init system will auto-generate one during boot.
RUN /etc/my_init.d/00_regen_ssh_host_keys.sh

# Copied command from https://github.com/rogaha/docker-desktop/blob/master/Dockerfile
# Configuring xdm to allow connections from any IP address and ssh to allow X11 Forwarding. 
RUN sed -i 's/DisplayManager.requestPort/!DisplayManager.requestPort/g' /etc/X11/xdm/xdm-config
RUN sed -i '/#any host/c\*' /etc/X11/xdm/Xaccess
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/Xorg 
RUN echo X11Forwarding yes >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config

# OMnet++ 5.1.1

# Create working directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/omnetpp
WORKDIR /usr/omnetpp

# Fetch Omnet++ source
RUN wget https:******omnetpp-5.1.1-src-linux.tgz
RUN tar -xf omnetpp-5.1.1-src-linux.tgz

# Path
ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/omnetpp/omnetpp-5.1.1/bin

# Configure and compile 
RUN cd omnetpp-5.1.1 && \ 
    xvfb-run ./configure && \ 
    make 

# Cleanup 
RUN apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt && \
    rm /usr/omnetpp/omnetpp-5.1.1-src-linux.tgz
```

Comment: Try to use `Bridge` instead of `transparent`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But isn't Bridge the default setting in docker? Even with a custom Bridge network i am not able to ssh into the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution that worked for me

First of all the linked Microsoft Article is only valid for windows container. 
[This](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/) Article explains very well how docker networks work.

To simplify the explanation i drew a simple example.[Simple ssh into docker network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mhx3d.png).

To be able to reach a container in bridged networks one is required to expose the necessary ports explicitly.

1. Expose Port

   `docker run -p 22 {$imageName}`
2. Find Port mapping on host machine

   `CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                              COMMAND           CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                   NAMES
   a2ec2bd2b53b        renderfehler/omnet_ide_baseimage   "/sbin/my_init"     17 hours ago        Up 17 hours         0.0.0.0:32773->22/tcp   tender_newton`
3. ssh onto container using mapped port

   `ssh -p 32772 root@0.0.0.0`